# Pulse width modulation for three phase voltage source inverter

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, inverter, three-phase

I have found a block diagram which discribes implementation of a modulator for the three phase voltage source inverter. I am not sure whether I fully understand this implementation of the modulator. I have decided to simulate this implementation of modulator in Scilab Xcos.

The overview of the Xcos block diagram is below
[image]

The internal details of the ***PWM block*** are following
[image]

The *Inverse Clarke transform block*
[image]

The *Pulse centering module* block
[image]

The *Comparator* block
[image]

The *Three phase voltage source inverter* block details are following
[image]

The *First sliding harmonic block* details
[image]

When I started the simulation I was surprised that the amplitude of the first harmonic of the line voltage at the output of the inverter is determined by the module of the voltage space vector \$|U^*|\$. I expected that the module of the voltage space vector \$|U^*|\$ should determine the amplitude of the phase voltage instead. 
Simulation results are on below given picture where

- *black trace  - line voltage*
- *blue trace   - first harmonic of the line voltage*
- *red trace    - phase voltage at the load*
- *yellow trace - first harmonic of the phase voltage at the load*

[image]

Please can anybody explain to me why the module of the voltage space vector \$|U^*|\$ determines amplitude of the first harmonic of the line voltage instead of amplitude of the first harmonic of the phase voltage of the load? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm getting to know 3 phase inverters and 3 phase electric motors. Where did you find this model? Or do you know where can I find similar models for Xcos?

Comment: @Felipe I have developed this model by myself. As far as I know there is nothing similar in Scilab/Xcos.